# fpdf: header not working in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I have consumed fpdf library and using it according the official documentation from fpdf.

I want to use header in my file but not able to use that, below is my code for same. Please correct my mistake why header is not coming..

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
function Header()
{
    // Select Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',5);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80,'ddd');
    // Framed title
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(20,10,'Title',1,1,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}
}

$pdf=new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',14);

$pdf->Cell(20,10,'Title',1,1,'C');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: You're not calling Header() nor instancing the PDF class anywhere in the sample code.

Comment: You must call the `PDF` class not `FPDF`

Answer (score 9):

Per PetrHejda's comment, all you should need to do is change

```
$pdf=new FPDF();
```

to

```
$pdf=new PDF();
```

Comment: @PetrHejda if you add your comment as an answer, I'll tell the OP to mark you as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Archit, you could also accept this answer...then this question will be listed as already answered one